Return ID with a prefix model
I'm currently working with Beanie ODM, FastAPI and MongoDB and facing a challenge with optimizing the way references are printed in my JSON responses.
Current Situation: For a Booking object, my current output looks like this:
{
  "_id": "66691ce3f75184ad17b7abd9",
  "account": {
    "id": "6630082da4ecb6802b241748",
    "collection": "account"
  },
  "hotel": {
    "id": "6660c3bb318e44905a3cff19",
    "collection": "hotel"
  },
  "arrival_date": "2024-06-12T00:00:00",
  "departure_date": "2024-06-13T00:00:00",
  "language": "en",
  "observations": "",
  "approved": false,
  "created_at": "2024-06-12T03:58:27.887000",
  "updated_at": "2024-06-12T03:58:27.887000"
}

Desired Output: I want to format the output so that it includes the collection prefix directly in the reference fields, like this:
{
  "id": "booking_66691ce3f75184ad17b7abd9",
  "account": "account_6630082da4ecb6802b241748",
  "hotel": "hotel_6660c3bb318e44905a3cff19",
  "arrival_date": "2024-06-12T00:00:00",
  "departure_date": "2024-06-13T00:00:00",
  "language": "en",
  "observations": "",
  "approved": false,
  "created_at": "2024-06-12T03:58:27.887000",
  "updated_at": "2024-06-12T03:58:27.887000"
}

Currently, to achieve this, I am fetching the booking details and then formatting each booking object individually. This approach is not optimal, especially when dealing with a large number of bookings (e.g., 10,000 bookings). It requires fetching all bookings and then iterating through each one to apply the formatting function, which is resource-intensive.
I'm considering exploring custom fields in Beanie or creating a new field class that inherits from the existing Field type (Link) to handle this more efficiently.

Are you using "fetch_links=true" like :
bookings = Booking.find_all(fetch_links=True).to_list();
?

You said "collection prefix" but for "hotel": { "id": "6660c3bb318e44905a3cff19", "collection": "hotels" } you have "hotel": "hotel_6660c3bb318e44905a3cff19". It should be "hotel": "hotels_6660c3bb318e44905a3cff19" with an s. Post your model definitions and bases for the relevant fields.

Whether you change the representation yourself or via a field definition/handler, it's still going to utilise resources. And doing it for 100K such objects was very fast (<0.1 secs): for d in lst: d['account'] = f"{d['account']['collection']}_{d['account']['id']}"  d['hotel'] = <as above>. It may not be clean code to do it for certain outputs but it's hardly resource-intensive.

Looks like you want to utilise Pydantics computed_field, here's my answer to a similar problem
